# Cockpit manage networking and updates in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, cockpit

No matter how many articles have i found and read about installing and using **Cockpit** on **Ubuntu**, but I am no able to manage Networking and Updates in same time. While I want to manage network, I must have **NetworkManager** service up and running, otherwise i can see just blank white sceen in Network tab. But while NetworkManager service is up and running, I am not able to manage updates (receiving "*Cannot refresh cache whilst offline*" error message). Does anyone has solution for this strange behaviour, please?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
sudo snap install network-manager && sudo snap remove network-manager && sudo shutdown -r now
```

Reference https://github.com/cockpit-project/cockpit/issues/8477#issuecomment-737046753

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunatelly this is not working on my testing server somehow. Network tab is missing completely after I remove Network Manager when I tried "snap method". It is strange, because, I am missing this tab even if I use "renderer method".

Comment: Perhaps do a fresh install of 20.04? I did a fresh install and ran updates without messing around too much. I did this on 6 separate servers and they all came good.